# How can one properly reduce lag in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been having a little bit of an issue running CS:GO. Whenever I play, at times it will be good, but then all of a sudden it will just get real blocky and laggy and my computer will start to freeze up. Is there any way I can fix this? I have all my settings to the lowest possible one, but it is still doing it. The game is constantly eating up all of my CPU and RAM when they *(Valve and others)* claim it can be ran on an old crappy computer.

Comment: It all depends on exactly what the lag looks like and what it does. If you can, try recording a video. I found many, many solutions for reducing lag in CS:GO but all for different reasons.

Comment: Are you talking about Network lag or FPS issues? Those are 2 fundamentally different things and not the same. To me this sounds like a graphics issue. Nevertheless, post your system specs, otherwise we cannot help you. And the old crappy computer is still not allowed to go under the minimum system requirements outlined on the store page.

Comment: Please post your system specifications, so that I can take a look at them and i'll see if your PC is good enough or not.
What we need is:
RAM
CPU
Graphic Card
Eventually, computer brand and model

Comment: I am currently at school right now, so I can't exactly tell you my PC specs, but I went to [SystemRequirementsLab](http://systemrequirementslab.com/cyri) and they said that my computer could handle it. Yet it still lags.

Comment: Read my answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191900/csgo-jolty-and-laggy-after-updating-to-vangaurd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea is to optimise your rates.

So for instance, for a 128 tick server:

```
rate 128000
cl_updaterate 128
cl_cmdrate 128
```