# Game is lagging severely after Operation Vanguard update

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've recently updated to the new Vanguard edition of CS GO. But now its impossible to play - the game is jolty and slow. Sometimes there are little bugs like my gun not appearing or the clicking warm up count down sound continuing into the round.

I've checked internet speeds and they are fine.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What are your internet speeds and what did you check? Bandwidth is not really important, but Ping is.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness bandwidth is about 25mbps. No idea how to check ping

Comment: Umm, don't you mean download speed? What region are you and what region are your settings in?

Comment: You can see the ping ingame on the score board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your video card drivers are up to date. If they are not, make sure you do a clean install from scratch, Nvidia has an option to do a "fresh install" If they are up to date, consider reinstall them and doing a fresh install anyways. Never upgrade your drivers using the utility your video card software installs along with the drivers. (ex: nvidia experience)
2. Make sure you do a Verify Integrity of Game Cache. (Last Option) You can get to this option by going to your steam library, Right click on CS:Go, go to properties, Then Local Files Tab.

[image]

3. If that doesn't work, Try re-installing cs:go, by Delete Local Game Content, and let it redownload and install the game fresh. (3rd option)